# How to get a call status while the call is still ongoing in Twilio

Tags: python, flask, twilio-api

I have a dialer program that uses twilio api to call and receive calls. The programs use calls and send me the status of the call after the call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="clientNo"></Dial>
</Response>
```

```
def call(self, receiver_no):
        try: 
            self.receiver_no = receiver_no
            url = 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/'
            twiml_url = 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH40da0740a457713cf079886772cacc4c?&clientNo='+self.receiver_no
            call = client.calls.create(
                to=self.receiver_no, # Any phone number
                from_=self.caller_no, # Your Twilio phone number
                url=twiml_url,
                status_callback='http://127.0.0.1:5000/webhook',
                status_callback_event=['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed']
                
            )
            call_status = client.calls(call.sid).fetch().status
            return call_status
        except (ConnectionError, TwilioRestException, requests.exceptions.RequestException) as e:
            print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
            return 'Not available'
```

```
@views.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle_webhook():
    call_status = request.form.get('CallStatus')
    call_duration = request.form.get('CallDuration')
    return call_status
```

When I run the program it takes sometime like it is a loop the it end the call. I would like the code to send me a call status that the callee has received a call without waiting for the call to end first. I have tried using status callbacks to so I can know the status of the call but I get the response after the call. Please help me with on how to get the call status while on the call.

Comment: The status callbacks should be send to you as the events occur, not after the call.
The URL for the callback should be a public URL so Twilio can send HTTP requests to it. `http://127.0.0.1:5000/webhook` would not work, but you can use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to make it public for local development.